# Make CSS hover stay within viewport

Tags: css, hover, viewport

I have a hover solution setup with CSS. However, the hover images don't respect the viewport and therefore end up displaying outside of it. I planned to simply create new classes specifying the offset depending on the location of the image within my design, but since I can't control the resolution the user is using, I was thinking there should be some way to force the hover to display within the viewport. Does anyone have an idea on how I can do this?

I have the following CSS:

```
.thumbnail:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span { 
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px;
    left: -1000px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    visibility: hidden;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img { 
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span { 
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0;
    left: 70px; 
}
```

To match the following thumbnails with hover:

```
<li>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="img thumbnail">
        <img src="1_s.jpg" />
        <span><img src="1_b.jpg" /></span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="img thumbnail">
        <img src="2_s.jpg" />
        <span><img src="2_b.jpg" /></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I have a sample page here displaying the behavior:

http://estorkdelivery.com/example/example2.html

Hover over the images at the bottom to see the hover image display outside of the viewport.

Thanks!

**Update 2/22/2012** I tested answer #1 below, but it introduced new issues such as the need to change the transparency and the need to have the hover image always display from the top left of the image - both issues I saw no way of modifying with the script options. Anyone have other suggestions or a way to modify the script in answer #1? Also, I should add what I'm looking for as more of the final result is the hover styling of images on istockphoto.com where the images always appear in the same spot to the left or right of the images they are hovering over and not based off the position of the mouse as you hover over the image.

Comment: hi Yazmin, i have updated my code to reflect what you asked. give it a try and let me know. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a bespoke plugin for you!

http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/tAECz/

Well, it's pretty basic but I think it meets your criteria. You can activate it in two ways:

1) If you can't be bothered creating thumbnails for every image, you can just simply list your images like this:

```
<ul id="istockWannabe">
    <li>
        <img src="imgURL" width="600" height="400" title="Description" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="imgURL" width="600" height="400" title="Description" />
    </li>
...
</ul>
```

2) If you really want to create your own thumbnails, your html should look like this:

```
<ul id="istockWannabe">
    <li>
        <span rel="largeImgURL"><img src="thumbURL" /><span class="iStockWannabe_description">Image description</span></span>
    </li>
...
</ul>
```

Either way you choose, you need to include jQuery 1.7+ in your page along with my plugin.

The very last thing you need to do is to activate it, if you're going for the first option, you can just include in your page following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#istockWannabe").istockWannabe();
    });
</script>
```

If you're going for the second option, you need to override default settings like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#istockWannabe").istockWannabe({ createThumbs: false });
    });
</script>
```

This is more like a prototype so it's quite limited in terms of functionaltiy but you can set some options like:
thumbMaxWidth: 100
thumbMaxHeight: 100 
tooltipWidth: 200
tooltipHeight: 150
transitionSpeed: 100

If you like it, I'm happy to spend some time on it and adjust it to suit your needs!

Comment: Adaz - This is pretty close to what iStock has and that is great! The only other major issue is that this doesn't address the viewport problem that started this question. Once I added a width to the UL container and some spacing for the LIs to stop the jsfiddle box from scrolling, the image displayed on hover still appears outside of the viewport. Suggestions? (BTW, writing something for me is above and beyond - I thank you for that! +1 to you!)

Comment: No worries! I'm not sure what exactly do you mean, could you send me your fiddle? I did some improvements, maybe that will sort out your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/tAECz/1/

Comment: Adaz - Your latest fiddle fixes the issue I was talking about previously. It works great if I don't need to change it from the default implementation you created, but when I tried to add options as suggested, I got an "unexpected token" error. I took what you were working with and created a fiddle that would mimic more what I'm doing on my end. Still getting that same error, too, along with the hover not staying within the viewport on the right side and rewriting itself underneath the text I need to keep within the LI tags: http://jsfiddle.net/ywickham/g7tDQ/4/

Comment: Hey Yazmin, I've just done more improvements, now you can see I use custom options: http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/rz2vH/ - rather than specifying margin left in the CSS, I've added options for tooltip offset top and left. 

Here's an example of the second implementation of my plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/adaz/AvYXE/. 

In case if you're lost, here's where you set options: 
$("#istockWannabe").iStockWannabe({ 
thumbMaxWidth: 50, 
thumbMaxHeight: 50, 
tooltipOffset: { top: 0, left: 120 } 
});

Answer (score 2):

Try the jQuery Tooltip:

**Here is an example according to your request:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/3X2eZ/

**DOCS**
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip
http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

**Quick instructions:**
1) Within the <head> load the css and scripts:

```
<link href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2) Still within the <head> place the execution script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".your-div").tooltip({
                    track: true,
                    delay: 0,
                    showURL: false,
                    fade: 250,
                    bodyHandler: function() {
                        return $($(this).next().html());
                    },
                    showURL: false
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The class '.my-div' will be used to display the image with the hover event.
The sibling div to '.my-div' must contain the hidden elements to make visible after hovering.

```
<ul>
    <li>
            <div class="my-div">
                <!-- Here comes the image with the hover event -->
            </div>
            <div class="active-hover">
                <!-- Here comes all the hidden elements I want to display while hovering the PREVIOUS div --><br />
                <!-- .active-hover must be set with display:none -->
            </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That's all!

Comment: This is a great answer, but it introduces a whole new set of issues. I'd need to remove the background transparency and to set the offset images to appear from the topleft corner of the image. I'm not seeing how to address either one of those issues in the documentation. :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a script, in the js you can change the width of the container.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/GgDqh/

UPDATED, NOW WORKS IN FIDDLE AND IS MORE ADAPTABLE.

Comment: I was testing this out on the site, but have to step away...will come back to it tonight. Thanks Cadence!

Comment: Hey Cadence - I was trying to work out your fiddle first since you initially answered the question, but the hovers still appear outside the view port for me so it doesn't solve the issue. :/

Comment: Have you tested it outside the fiddle? There it works better. Notice I've replaced the initial script.

Comment: Yes, I did test it outside of fiddle first before commenting and I was only able to return to testing after you made your update (per my previous comment above), so I tested your latest version.

Comment: Can you tell me in which situation it it failing? I know it isn't perfect specially in very small windows, or when it has very few photos. But for me it worked well and in a very similar way to the istock script in 960 and 600px scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

> - **demo** : http://so.lucafilosofi.com/make-css-hover-stay-within-viewport

look at the source code

**NB:** this does not take in consideration cases in which the popup is bigger then the window, in this case you should not only change the offset position but you have to resize the popup to fit the window.

Comment: Thank you aSeptik, but I'm not looking to make the window scroll to display the hover image.

Comment: @rpearce: tnx to notice the broken link, i have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I however solved the problem only for the Y-axis. For the horizontal offset it should be the same. [See how it works here](http://jsbin.com/ixoleq/3/edit).
I set the `top` to exactly the side of the image * -1, this aligns the image at the bottom if it doesn't fit, change that value to whatever you want. The images are very big and this script is however not gonna be bulletproof. You would have to get the whole visible area to make sure it doesn't cut out on the other side when you re-position it.

The markup hasn't changed, I just added the Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".thumbnail > img").mouseenter(function(){

        var winSize = $(window).height();
        var winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var linkOffset = $(this).offset().top - winScrollTop + 75; 
        // 75px is the height of the img. To get the offset().bottom . Get rid of the scroll too.
        var imgHover = $(this).next("span");
        var imgHoverHeight = parseInt(imgHover.children("img").attr("height"));
        var spaceDif = winSize-linkOffset;
        if(spaceDif < imgHoverHeight){
            imgHover.css("top", -imgHoverHeight+"px");
          //it doesn't have to be -imgHoverHeight. Tweak this value to get better results           
        }

    }); 

    $(".thumbnail > img").mouseout(function(){

        $("span").css("top", "0");

    });
});
```

Hope it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... seems comparatively cool!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hover Test</title>
    <style>
        li {margin-bottom: 100px;}
        .thumbnail{position: relative;z-index: 0;}
        .thumbnail:hover{background-color: transparent;z-index: 50;}
        .thumbnail div{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/position: absolute;padding: 5px;left: -1000px;border: 1px dashed gray;visibility: hidden;color: black;text-decoration: none;}
        .thumbnail div img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/border-width: 0;padding: 2px;}
        .thumbnail:hover div{ /*CSS for enlarged image on hover*/visibility: visible;top: 0;left: 70px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="img thumbnail">
            <img src="1_s.jpg">
            <div><img src="1_b.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" class="img thumbnail">
            <img src="2_s.jpg">
            <div><img src="2_b.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com" class="img thumbnail">
            <img src="3_s.jpg">
            <div><img src="3_b.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.babycenter.com" class="img thumbnail">
            <img src="4_s.jpg">
            <div><img src="4_b.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.food.com" class="img thumbnail">
            <img src="5_s.jpg">
            <div><img src="5_b.jpg"></div>
        </a>
    </li>       
</body>
```